# How do I choose a logo according to device

Tags: javascript

I’m developing a site with WP. I’d like to show a different heading for phone, for tablet and for desktop. I have three different logos. How do I do that?

Comment: You can use media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@media` query's to display different styles in different medias

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should help

```
        <style>
      /* hide mobile version by default */
      .logo .mobile {
        display: none;
      }
      /* when screen is less than 600px wide
         show mobile version and hide desktop */
      @media (max-width: 600px) {
        .logo .mobile {
          display: block;
        }
        .logo .desktop {
          display: none;
        }
      }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append three different logos into your file.php like this:

```
<img class="header-img" src="path_to_desktop">
<img class="tablet-header-img" src="path_to_tablet.jpg">
<img class="mobile-header-img" src="path_to_mobile.jpg">
```

And add this one into your css:

```
.mobile-header-img, .tablet-header-img, .header-img {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .mobile-header-img {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
    .tablet-header-img {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1281px) {
    .header-img {
        display: block;
    }
}
```